# segmentation fault while installing rasa_nlu

Tags: python, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, rasa-nlu

I am trying to use RASA to build a chatbot but I have an issue with the installation of RASA_NLU 
Here is the line I entered

```
pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pip install rasa_nlu --no-cache-dir
python -m rasa_nlu.server &
```

Or manually by downloading git and installing package:

```
git clone git@github.com:RasaHQ/rasa_nlu.git
cd rasa_nlu
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
```

Before installing `scrapy` on Ubuntu 9.10 or above, you'll ned to run this first:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

and afterwards `pip install spacy`

Safest way is to install on virtual environment. If none of these works, consider reinstallig Python.

More about segmentation fault on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138407/what-is-a-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 0):

try installing rasa_nlu with those command

$git clone https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu.git

$cd rasa_nlu

$pip install -r alt_requirements/requirements_full.txt

that resolve the majority of issues related to dependencies

for more info visit : https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/installation/

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try with sudo
"sudo pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]"

Comment: Using `sudo` is bad, more so when dealing with Python. The way, OP did is right and the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps, ask the OP to rephrase the question or add more information (e.g. debug logs, etc.).